Error tras clonar un proyecto de github de laravel no conecta
Tras clonar para probar que todo funcionaba, y al lanzar las migraciones, esperando que no hiciera nada pues estaba la base y esperando que no tirara error.....lo tiro:
"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as name, (data_length + index_length) as size, table_comment as comment, engine as engine, table_collation as collation from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'contaBase' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)"
Hay errores similares, pero no se arregla con las soluciones que dan o por lo menos, no me funcionan a mi, y no se por qué sale dicho error;
"claramente, me dice que no conecta, que rechaza la conexión, comprobé el archivo de configuración tanto del database.conf, como del .env de las variables del entorno, como tengo el de entorno, se fija  primero en esas reglas/configuracion, aqui va la parte del database:
DB_COLLATION=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=contaBase
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=(secretpassword)

donde secretpassword introducida correctamente.....
Alguna idea de donde proviene el error, como algo que se "guardara" en alguna configuracion y de conflicto?
Añado los datos de los usuarios de mysql:
Esto son los permisos de "sail"(usuario que se crea con laravel y el archivo de variables de entorno): mysql> SHOW GRANTS; | Grants for sail@% | | GRANT USAGE ON . TO sail@% | | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON contaBase.* TO sail@% | | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testing%.* TO sail@% | 3 rows in set (0.00 sec) mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER(); | CURRENT_USER() | | sail@% | 1 row in set (0.01 sec)
Y estos los de root: | Grants for root@% | | GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON . TO root@% WITH GRANT OPTION|APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ADMIN,AUDIT_ABORT_EXEMPT,AUDIT_ADMIN,AUTHENTICATION_POLICY_ADMIN,BACKUP_ADMIN,BINLOG_ADMIN,BINLOG_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,CLONE_ADMIN,CONNECTION_ADMIN,ENCRYPTION_KEY_ADMIN,FIREWALL_EXEMPT,FLUSH_OPTIMIZER_COSTS,FLUSH_STATUS,FLUSH_TABLES,FLUSH_USER_RESOURCES,GROUP_REPLICATION_ADMIN,GROUP_REPLICATION_STREAM,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ARCHIVE,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ENABLE,PASSWORDLESS_USER_ADMIN,PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN,REPLICATION_APPLIER,REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,SENSITIVE_VARIABLES_OBSERVER,SERVICE_CONNECTION_ADMIN,SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN,SET_USER_ID,SHOW_ROUTINE,SYSTEM_USER,SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN,TABLE_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,XA_RECOVER_ADMIN ON . TO root@% WITH GRANT OPTION | | GRANT PROXY ON @ TO root@% WITH GRANT OPTION| 3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
Y estos los usuarios que hay:
mysql> SELECT user FROM mysql.user;

| user             |
+------------------+
| root             |
| sail             |
| healthchecker    |
| mysql.infoschema |
| mysql.session    |
| mysql.sys        |
| root             |
+------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| root             | %         |
| sail             | %         |
| healthchecker    | localhost |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)


Copia y pega desde el comando, y todo el error, pegalo como texto, no sirven las imagenes acá.

La primera linea, la de :
DB_COLLATION, no estaba, fue un "arreglo", pero con eso solo no bastó

Tras investigar un poco mas, no se si "rompí" mas el asunto, use:
"php artisan config:cache"
no dio error, pero, el error que da ahora, cambia, y se que es de acceso, porque dice que no encuentra una carpeta, ni puede crearla por permisos, así que, no se arreglo mucho el problema......; lo extraño, es que, tengo acceso a la base de datos desde el heidi, pero lo demas, como que coge otra configuración, o es la impresión que me da al no darme "permisos"

Esto es lo que me dice al intentar conectar a la aplicación desde navegador:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.1' (using password: YES)
select * from (tabla)
tabla es la tabla a la que intento acceder

Borre la base de datos, pues tenia poco y con los seeds lo recuperaba, a la hora de conectar con el heidi, borrando lo que había y dándole a nuevo, poniendo todo, me da el mismo error que al intentar acceder a la web:
Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.1' (using password: YES)
me creo que tengo la carpeta de configuración vieja o algo dando conflicto.

Que ip mas rara es esa, que paso con localhost ?

Es lo que me pregunto yo...., se ve que da conflicto algo "viejo" y no doy con la tecla para "borrar" ese algo "viejo", borre incluso los volúmenes del docker, pero sin resultados, al menos visibles

Asegurado otra vez el borrado del docker y volúmenes, vuelto a instalarlo, ahora, si me crea la base, y me deja conectar con heidi, no cambie la contraseña, no deja "acceder" a cosas de esquemas, sigue sin dejarme dándome el mismo error:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as name, (data_length + index_length) as size, table_comment as comment, engine as engine, table_collation as collation from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'contaBase' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

Sigue rechazando la conexión. Hay mas errores en los log de mysql ? Utiliza en la terminal mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u tu_usuario -p para ver si conectas. Y ya probaste a cambiar la IP por localhost cierto ?

Lo de la ip por localhost si lo probe, da igual como lo deje, los logs ahora lo miro, y desde el terminal, si conecta con root y la contraseña que hay en el archivo de variables de entorno,(probado como root de momento, en este archivo esta sail de usuario), como dije, ahora me conecta, pero "limitado" o algo por el estilo, me deja crear a mano en el heidi los datos de las tablas, pero no me deja seedear, ni migrar con el "fresh" y las seeds......Pero almenos, puedo ir haciendo pruebas...

Y revisaste los permisos del usuario ? Si no, entregalos todos.

Los logs me muestran lo que intente hacer, el conection refused etc; me queda comprobar los permisos, que algo a de quedar de la configuración vieja, voy a ver eso, a ver como están.....si es que estan

Mirando los usuarios de mysql veo algo....que no comprobé antes, hay dos "root", no se si por eso da errores, pero tiene todas las papeletas para que sea lo que da fallo....

Esto son los permisos de "sail"(usuario que se crea con laravel y el archivo de variables de entorno):
mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
| Grants for sail@%                                   |
| GRANT USAGE ON . TO sail@%                    |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON contaBase.* TO sail@% |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testing%.* TO sail@%  |
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
| CURRENT_USER() |
| sail@%         |
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Y estos los de root:
| Grants for root@% |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON . TO root@% WITH GRANT OPTION|

Y esto:
| GRANT APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ADMIN,AUDIT_ABORT_EXEMPT,AUDIT_ADMIN,AUTHENTICATION_POLICY_ADMIN,BACKUP_ADMIN,BINLOG_ADMIN,BINLOG_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,CLONE_ADMIN,CONNECTION_ADMIN,ENCRYPTION_KEY_ADMIN,FIREWALL_EXEMPT,FLUSH_OPTIMIZER_COSTS,FLUSH_STATUS,FLUSH_TABLES,FLUSH_USER_RESOURCES,GROUP_REPLICATION_ADMIN,GROUP_REPLICATION_STREAM,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ARCHIVE,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ENABLE,PASSWORDLESS_USER_ADMIN,PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN,REPLICATION_APPLIER,REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,SENSITIVE_VARIABLES_OBSERVER,SERVICE_CONNECTION_ADMIN,SESSION_V

ARIABLES_ADMIN,SET_USER_ID,SHOW_ROUTINE,SYSTEM_USER,SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN,TABLE_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,XA_RECOVER_ADMIN ON . TO root@% WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON @ TO root@% WITH GRANT OPTION|
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Muchos para root....pero no se porque, o cual (de los usuarios) usa el comando de migrar, que sigue dando el rechazo de la conexión

Por favor, añade todo eso a la publicación, y detalla eso de los 2 usuarios, root, por que no me parece correcto

A ello voy, añado lo que había y lo de los dos usuarios roo

Tras "experimentar" un poco, cambiándole los permisos a sail, todo sigue igual, al migrar me rechaza, al seedear, no, pero no hace nada, y acceso a la base de datos, con heidi si me lo concede, pero no como debería.
(Ni idea de porque tengo dos usuarios root en la base, ni que tocar mas para que pueda funcionar como debe)
